# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|\cos n|}$

Tags: calculus

I have seen the proof of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|\sin n|}=1$ by using Louivile number. In a similar way , I tried
to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|\cos n|}=1$ by using Dirichlet 's approximation theorem:

If $\omega$ is an irrational number ,then  there exist infinite many positive integer $p_n,q_n (q_n>1)$  such that
$$ \left| \omega-\frac{p_n }{q_n }\right|<\frac{1}{q_n^2 }.$$

Take $\omega=\pi$, then
$$ \left| q_n\pi-p_n\right|<\frac{1}{q_n }.$$
Hence $|\cos p_n|=\cos\left| q_n\pi-p_n\right|>\cos\frac{1}{q_n}$.

Therefore we have $\sqrt[n]{|\cos p_n|}>\sqrt[n]{\cos\frac{1}{q_n}}\to 1. (n\to \infty)$

Here the set $\{p_n\}$ is just a part of the natural number set $\mathbb{N}.$  I donot know how to  go further.

I would appreciate if someone could give some suggestions and comments. Welcome new proof. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Dirichlet approximation goes in the wrong direction.  You need the fact that rational approximations of $\pi$
can't be too good, not the fact that there are approximations that are not too bad.

In order to have $|\cos(n)|^{1/n} < 1-\epsilon$
(for some constant $\epsilon \in (0,1)$) we would need
$|\cos(n)| < (1-\epsilon)^n$, which would imply
$|n - k\pi/2| < 2 (1-\epsilon)^n$ for some odd $k$,
and thus $|\pi - 2n/k| < 4 (1-\epsilon)^n/k$.  Now it is known that $\pi$ has finite [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure): the
best bound at the moment  ([Zeilberger and Zudlin 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06345)) on the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is that it is at most $7.103205334137$.  That is, for any $\mu$ greater than that number, there are at most finitely many pairs of positive integers $p,q$ with
$$ \left| \pi - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^\mu} $$
We want to take $p=2n$, $q=k$, and note that $(1-\epsilon)^n/k < 1/k^\mu$ for sufficiently large $n$ and $k$ when $2n/k$ is near $\pi$.  The conclusion is that $|\cos(n)|^{1/n} \ge 1-\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, and thus $|\cos(n)|^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The definition of irrationality measure is equivalent to the statement that if $x$ has irrationality measure $\mu$, then $\mu$ is the smallest number such that the inequality $$|x-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^{\mu}} $$ holds only for at most finite integers $p,q.$
 
 
 
   Hence by the  definition, for any $\mu$ greater than $7.103205334137$,    the inequality
$$ \left| \pi - \frac{p}{q} \right| \geq  \frac{1}{q^\mu} $$
 holds for all integers $p, q$ with $q $  sufficiently large. Is it right?